# Como escolher a pasta padrão ao executar as funções "styles" e "scripts" do Elixir?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gulp

Usando o Laravel Elixir, eu costumo usar as funções `styles` e `scripts` para concatenar os assets para um arquivo só. Porém, parece que, por padrão, essas duas funções tentam ler arquivos da pasta `resources/assets`.

Sempre que eu preciso efetuar essas operações na pasta `node_modules`, eu preciso colocar "dois-pontos" no caminho do arquivo, o que faz a tarefa ficar bastante enfadonha.

Meu arquivo `gulpfile.js` está assim:

```
elixir(function (mix) {

    mix.styles([
        '../../../node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.css',
        '../../../node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.css',
        '../../../node_modules/ionicons/dist/css/ionicons.css'
    ], 'public/css/_compiled.css');
});
```

Existe alguma maneira de definir a pasta padrão da leitura desses arquivo,  para eu evitar a repetição de `../../../node_modules/`?

Comment: `elixir.config.assetsDir = 'node_modules/js/';`

Comment: Bacana, acho que isso aí resolve também. Seria interessante se tivesse como fazer uma definição de pasta padrão por chamada de `styles` ou `scripts`.